# Conversion between unknown map projections?

Tags: reprojection-mathematics

So I have two maps

- One that divides regions into small provinces (represented with `"ID"s`)
- Another showing which country controlled each part (shown with colours)

I want to overlay them to see which provinces would be controlled by each country.

The issue is that the maps have different projections. The one with the provinces is from Hearts of Iron IV and since I'm in Europe, it essentially is using the Miller Projection.

But I'm not sure which projection the other one is using. This was my attempt to overlay the two:

[image: Very messy attempt at overlaying them]

My question is: What is the best way to do this? Is there a program for it? Should I try even thinner strips? Maybe a mathematical approach is best?

[Here's](https://www.deviantart.com/leon1900/art/Spain-map-with-rivers-and-cities-784640078) the second (non-province-containing) map if anyone thinks they'd be able to identify the projection.

Comment: That link points to an image of a map, right? Wouldn't it be easier to just download a shapefile (or something similar) with country borders? There are several places where you can get this data as vectors instead of an image. BTW which software are you using?